# Joins not working in Django

Tags: python, django, join, django-models, django-queryset

I`m trying to write an inner join from two models, but I stuck in between.

My **models.py** page is:

```
class MovieDetails(models.Model):
   moviename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   movieid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.movieid

class TheaterBase(models.Model):
    theatername = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    theaterid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.theaterid

class MovieActiveDays(models.Model):
     moviedetails = models.ForeignKey(MovieDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     theaterbase = models.ForeignKey(TheaterBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     activedayid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.activedayid
```

In My **Views.py** page:

```
moviedetails_id = MovieActiveDays.objects.filter(theaterbase=theaterid, ).values('moviedetails_id')
result= MovieDetails.objects.filter(movieid=moviedetails_id)
```

The First line filters the movies depending upon the theaters.
The second line will fetch more than 1 row from the database.
And whenever I try to sent the **result** to html **template** then it prints only the moviedetails_id but not the name of the movie or its contents.
How do I need to print all the contents of the moviedetails table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not be thinking in terms of joins. Tell us what you are trying to do and what output you want.

Comment: Please show the full (relevant) view also

Comment: @DanielRoseman
I want to display the name of the movie(from **MovieDetails**) which is currently being projected in a particular theater(from **TheaterBase**).
As movies will change, but theaters wont. so to join both these Models, I created another Model named **MovieActiveDetails** which stores only current movies which were being played in the theaters.

Comment: Ex: The users selects a theater (1021) & in that theater(1021), the MovieActiveDetails says that 4 movies are played (namely: 5001,5002,5003,5004) and now, I want to display the names of those 4 movies. But the **main problem** is I cant display all those 4 movies. the 2nd line in views.py shows only 1 movie.

How to display all the details of the 4 movies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental principle is to deal with these as objects, not as database tables. You need movie details, so start with that. You can then follow the relationships via Django's double-underscore syntax. So:

```
MovieDetails.objects.filter(movieactivedays__theaterbase_id=theaterid)
```

We can make this better by realising that MovieActiveDays is a through table in a many-to-many between MovieDetails and TheaterBase:

```
class MovieDetails(models.Model):
    ...
    theatres = models.ManyToManyField('TheaterBase', through='MovieActiveDays')
```

Now we can shorten the query:

```
MovieDetails.objects.filter(theatres=theaterid)
```

and Django will take care of all the joins for us.

Answer (score 0):

here result is the object of MovieDetails so you can get

movie_name= result.moviename